# Список ListView как в Gmail

Tags: android, listview

Привет все, я хочу реализовать свое приложение на примере Gmail ListView.

[image: скриншот]

Можете мне помочь?

Comment: Где хранятся данные, которые вы собираетесь выводить в этот список: файл , БД , сервер ?

Comment: Данные хранятся  в Базе Данных

Comment: @VitaliySivolotskiy если данные в базе, то используйте loader для вывода, вот [ссылка](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) на официальный источник

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать RecyclerView. В вашем (activity, fragment) создаете RecyclerView в **activity_main.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyGmailListAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyGmailListAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class MyGmailListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UIHolder> {

        private Cursor c;

        @Override
        public UIHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return new UIHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(UIHolder uiHolder, int i) {
            c.moveToPosition(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return c == null ? 0 : c.getCount();
        }

        public void changeCursor(Cursor c) {
            this.c = c;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class UIHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView title;
        TextView time;
        TextView description;
        ImageView star;
        View itemClick;

        public UIHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            star = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.star);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            itemClick = v.findViewById(R.id.item);

            itemClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    long itemId = (Long) v.getTag();
                    //action for item click
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

В build.gradle обязательно нужно добавить строки:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

**item.xml**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="42dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
            tools:text="Hello Header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="News:Tip Google Play" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/description"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="3:05PM" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Посмотрите еще оф. [доку](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: Во первых, для работы с курсором в наше время рекомендуется использовать `CursorLoader` - этой части нет вовсе. Потом, вас не смущает , что ваш код несколько нерабочий ? В активити вы создаете экземпляр от одного адаптера, в качестве примера предлагаете другой, который не имеет конструктора и способ получения курсора в адаптер весьма туманен. То, что предложенная к инфлейту `my_gmail_list_view` и есть та самая "накидал еще разметку .." тоже ниоткуда не следует. На последок, зачем подключать библиотеку `cardview`, если он не используется ? текущие версии библиотек поддержки: 22.2.0

Comment: Пожалуйста, если решили написать пример реализации, сделайте его законченным и понятным для новичка